# add new select option with an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, attributes

I want to add the href attribute to my select list (CountryList) elements:

```
var s = document.getElementById('CountryList');

var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "FR";
option.value = "FR";
option.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.facebook.com/');
s.add(option);

var option2 = document.createElement("option");
option2.text = "EN";
option2.value = "US";
option2.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.facebook.com/');
s.add(option2);

var option3 = document.createElement("option");
option3.text = "AR";
option3.value = "AR";
option3.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.google.com/');
s.add(option3);

var option4 = document.createElement("option");
option4.text = "ES";
option4.value = "ES";
option4.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.yahoo.com/');
s.add(option4);

var option5 = document.createElement("option");
option5.text = "IT";
option5.value = "IT";
option5.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.youtube.com/');
s.add(option5);
```

When I select an option it should redirect me to the specific href address, but currently it just redirects me to "yahoo" and "youtube", while the other elements don't redirect.

Comment: And what is triggering the redirection from this `href` attribute of a selected option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
    var s = document.getElementById('CountryList');
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "FR";
    option.value = "FR";
    option.setAttribute('data-href','https://www.facebook.com/') ;
    s.add(option);

     var option2 = document.createElement("option");
     option2.text = "EN";
     option2.value = "US";
     option2.setAttribute('data-href','https://www.facebook.com/') ;

     s.add(option2);
     var option3 = document.createElement("option");
     option3.text = "AR";
     option3.value = "AR";
     option3.setAttribute('data-href','https://www.google.com/') ;

     s.add(option3);
     var option4 = document.createElement("option");
     option4.text = "ES";
     option4.value = "ES";
     option4.setAttribute('data-href','https://www.yahoo.com/') ;

     s.add(option4);
     var option5 = document.createElement("option");
     option5.text = "IT";
     option5.value = "IT";
     option5.setAttribute('data-href','https://www.youtube.com/') ;

     s.add(option5);
     
     function redirect(obj){
     window.open(obj.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute("data-href"))
        
     }
```

```html
<select id="CountryList" onchange="redirect(this);">
<option>Select Country</option>
</select>
```

Comment: As OP has no use for `value` attribute, a better way is to set the `value` to url of the page. That way, there won't be a need for the `redirect` function by adding this `onChange="window.location.href=this.value"`

Comment: yeah that is also one approach

Comment: yeah it's easier like that , but i wanted to keep the value because i need it in another thing 
thanks for helping :D

Comment: Welcome. happy to hear this is helpful for you :) :D

Answer (score 2):

After you define `var s=document...` add this:

```
s.onchange = function() {
    var sel = this.options.selectedIndex;
    window.location = this.options[sel].getAttribute('href');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is puzzling to me, since it was tagged `jquery` but you are avoiding a lot of obvious jQuery APIs to make this simpler.

```js
var countries = $('#CountryList');

countries.append([
  $('<option></option>').text('FR').attr({
    value: 'FR',
    href: 'https://www.facebook.com/'
  }),
  $('<option></option>').text('EN').attr({
    value: 'US',
    href: 'https://www.facebook.com/'
  })
])

countries.on('change', function () {
  window.location = $(this).find(':selected').attr('href');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="CountryList"></select>
```

Comment: @MaryemSamet if you're doing a lot of HTML node creation in JS, I would recommend using a helper lib like [crel](https://github.com/KoryNunn/crel)